# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple, problem with density formula

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror

I am pretty new with Python and I am given a task to create a model in Python. 
I have a problem with this formula: 
`density = p/(0.1921 * (T+273.1))`.
It keeps saying: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple`.

Does anyone know the solution?

```
p = 0.699 * exp**(-0.00009 * h) 
T = -23,4 - 0.00222 * h
rho = p/(0.1921 * (T+273.1))
```

Comment: Try replacing your `p` and `t` values with simpler values, to see where the error might be. I suspect it thinks your `T = -23,4` is a tuple, and then is trying to concatenate `T + 273.1`, which would be a tuple (-23,4) and a float (273.1) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Answer (score 1):

The error came from the usage of the comma in the calculation of `T`:

```
T = -23,4 - 0.00222 * h
```

In the Python grammar definition the comma `,` character, among other things, is the value separator for collections like `tuple`, `list`, etc.. You should use the dot `.` charater instead to forge floats, as in the following:

```
T = -23.4 - 0.00222 * h
```

Comment: You're welcome! Not so much stupid anyway, some countries, like the mine one, actually make use of comma as separator for decimal digits!